# Trouble installing downloaded program

Tags: installation, command-line

I purchased and downloaded Celtx and I'm having trouble installing it (in Ubuntu 13.04). I'm a Linux newbie (literally had it for four days) so please be kind and don't assume much experience with the command line, I'm still learning. The folder with all related files/packages etc. is under "Downloads" and I have tried several commands to try and install but I'm just not doing it right and would appreciate help with exactly what command(s) to use. Sudo apt-get install celtx did not work. I'm assuming I'm missing a step somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please add information about the file(s) you have downloaded (that way we don't have to go and google for Celtx just to found out this). You see, depending on the type of file(s) there are different procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit confusing with all the ways to install. 
I think I have found the wiki...
http://wiki.celtx.com/index.php?title=Installation#For_Linux
it looks like you need to move the extracted files into the /usr/local
mv Downloads/Celtx /usr/local
run this to install 
sudo /usr/local/celtx/celtx
and thereafter use it like this
 /usr/local/celtx/celtx

For further reference:
is it a folder that you had from an archive file with a configure file?
--> in this case hopefully there is a readme or an install file in the top of the directory. if you "cd Downloads/name(e.g celtx-xx)" there should be one of these. usually it will tell you to do these commands in the directory
./configure
make
sudo make install

but do whatever it says

Or did you download a file that ends in .deb ?
this kind you can double click and it will try to open the package manager for you

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is taken directly from their wiki at http://wiki.celtx.com/index.php?title=Installation and is copied here in case someone else needs it.

> You can install Celtx by extracting the downloaded archive into your
>   home folder (e.g. /home/yourusername/bin) and run the application from
>   there. However, installing the software as a non-root user and in a
>   local folder means that only this single user will have access to it.
>   If you want all users to have access to it, Celtx must be installed
>   and run once as the root user. A typical installation from an
>   administrator account is done as follows: (copy - Ctrl+C - and paste -
>   Maj+Ins - the following code lines, one by one, in a Terminal window
>   -Ctrl+Alt+T) cd /usr/local If you are installing Celtx 1.0, then use this: sudo tar zxf /path/to/Celtx.tar.gz If you are installing Celtx
>   2.0, then use this: sudo tar xjf /path/to/Celtx.tar.bz2 (enter your password) sudo /usr/local/celtx/celtx If you get an error error while
>   loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory then you need to install a package
>   that contains libstdc++.so.5. On Redhat and Ubuntu, this is the
>   compat-libstdc++ package. On Gentoo, it's just called lib-compat. In
>   openSUSE 11.3 it's called libstdc++33-32bit & libstdc++33, and can be
>   installed through YaST2. You might be able to install it using yum
>   install compat-libstdc++ Now any user can run it using
>   /usr/local/celtx/celtx. If you're running a 64-bit build, ensure the
>   32-bit libraries are installed. Just search for the string "ia32"
>   within Synaptic. You might have to install the normal "ia32-libs",
>   "ia32-libs-gtk" and perhaps other required libraries. Ubuntu sometimes
>   creates the preference files (~/.celtx, ~/.greyfirst) as root-only and
>   the program will install but can only be run as root. To fix this
>   easily, you can delete the files from root (sudo rm -r ~/.celtx and
>   sudo rm -r ~/.greyfirst (don't use sudo rm -r on its own as this will
>   delete all your files)). Celtx will then create new preferences files.
>   Alternatively you can change the permissions of the files from root.

Answer (score 0):

First download either [Celtx-2.9.7 for Ubuntu Linux 32-bit](http://download.celtx.com/2.9.7/Celtx-2.9.7.tar.bz2), or [Celtx-2.9.7 for Ubuntu Linux 64-bit](http://download.celtx.com/2.9.7/Celtx-2.9.7-64.tar.bz2).  The instructions below assume that the file was downloaded to the Downloads folder.  If you downloaded it to a different folder, make sure you change the folder in the second command from Downloads to the folder name wjere the file was downloaded.

To install Celtx for all users to have access to, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the `/usr/local` folder, run the command(s) below:

```
cd /usr/local
sudo tar xjf ~/Downloads/Celtx-*.tar.bz2
```

Then just start the application

```
sudo /usr/local/celtx/celtx
```